# QGIS Multi distance buffer units do not align with the main layer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, buffer

I have a buildings shapefile of Beijing. I know the projection WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_50N
WKID: 32650 Authority: EPSG
So I would like to create multi distance buffer from a central point but when I do so, buffer of 1 m covers 3x size of the city. I change the projection of the layer when it was uploaded and checked all the settings to match. Tried to reopen the layer but still have the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Beijing buffer]
[image: CRS WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_50N]

Comment: it looks like a 1 degree buffer (not 1 meter)

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate? Im new to qgis.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65503/projection-change-to-create-buffer-in-qgis

Comment: Thank you, but that did not work in my Qgis, so colleague did it in ArcGIS and send me the new file.